# Better way to path a file using require()

Tags: php, include, require-once

```
require( dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname( __FILE__ ))))))).'/wp-load.php' );
```

this is the code im using at present.
The code is in a file called config.php

This is the structure :

wordpress\wp-content\themes\\plugins\shortcodes-ultimate\lib\config.php

and I need to reach to "wordpress/wp-load.php" .

get_bloginfo() doesn't work in config.php
How could I include it in a simpler manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
require("../../../../../../wp-load.php");
```

?

And, do you really mean for your plugin to be located within a theme?

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for. I had tried it but could never figure out how to calculate the number of "../" to have in the link and yes i need to include the plugin since I don't want to ask each user to install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path to `wordpress` to your include path somewhere early in your scripts, then us the "short" version for all of your includes:

```
set_include_path("/path/to/wordpress" . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . get_include_path());
...
require("wp-load.php");
```

Note that you should also inspect the path and see if it's what you anticipate. There's a small chance that the wordpress directory is already somewhere in your path and that the issue  is the leading `/`, (i.e. keep in mind that the paths `"/wp-load.php"` is *VERY* different from `"wp-load.php"`

Also note that "/path/to/wordpress" can be relative, too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little something to get the amount of `../`'s necessary to find the wp-load.php (at least if your code is in the wp-content):

```
$current = preg_split('/\//', preg_split('/wp-content/', getcwd())[1]);
$line = '';
foreach($current as $dots) {
    $line .='../';
}
require($line.'wp-load.php');
```